# Why is KivyMD on_touch_down event triggering multiple items?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a screen in my KivyMD app with a list of items. My objective is to navigate to different screens depending on the item clicked. I noticed that no matter which item I chose, the next screen would or wouldn't be related to the item clicked. It seems random.

Below is a reproducible example. To simplify, I deleted most items and replaced the navigation with a simple print function.

**When clicking an item or the "cancel" button, multiple texts are printed as if I had clicked on more than 1 element of the screen (e.g. a click on item1 results in "item3 item2 item1" being printed) I suspect this is why the navigation wasn't consistent**

I find this confusing. Could someone explain me what's going on here?  Thanks :)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    name: "screen1"         
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            id : tb_screen1
            title: "Select Item"
            on_touch_down:   
                app.p(self.title)
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "item1"
                    on_touch_down:   
                        app.p(self.text)
                        
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "item2"
                    on_touch_down:
                        app.p(self.text)
                          
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "item3"
                    on_touch_down:
                        app.p(self.text)
                           
                        
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDFloatLayout:                           
                MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                    text: "Cancel"
                    on_press:
                        app.p(self.text)

'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def p(self,text):
        print(text)

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the designed behavior of the `touch` event processing. The `touch` events get passed to all the widgets, and each widget is responsible for determining if it should respond to the `touch`. Widgets that extend `ButtonBehavior` (like `OneLineListItem` and `MDRectangleFlatIconButton`) have that test built into the `on_press` and `on_release` behaviors, so you can just use `on_press` or `on_release` for those Widgets (instead on `on_touch_down`).

The `MDToolbar` does not have `ButtonBehavior`, so you would have to add that test to your `on_touch_down`. You can do that like this:

```
    MDToolbar:
        id : tb_screen1
        title: "Select Item"
        on_touch_down:
            app.p(self.title) if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) else False
```

The above `kv` code calls the `app.p(self.title)` only if the touch point is within the bounds of the `MDToolbar`. The `args` above is a keyword in kivy (see [keywords](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)). The `args[1]` is the `touch`, and the `pos` is the position of that `touch`. The preceding `*` expands the `pos` to its `x`, `y` components (as the `collide_point()` method expects).

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Anderson for this well-written answer. I was able to solve the issue and understand what's going on.